# Java Hibernate H2-sql database

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, h2

I have a java program that is annotated to create tables in a test database. Right now I get 3 tables created with my annotations and I have a SQL statement that works that JOINS all the 3 tables into one and displays the information way better than to have to check all 3 tables individually.

Iam wondering if there is a way to incorporate my SQL statement into that database so that when i start the program i dont have to write the statement every time to join the 3 tables. Is it possible to apply a SQL statement in **application.properties** file that creates a VIEW TABLE automatically that joins the 3 tables? Or is there a simpler way? maybe write a sql query in the java code that does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JDBCTemplate and execute native SQL query adding mapping to convert query results to Java POJO class - DTO. (See [the example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/))

Or you can use H2 [CREATE VIEW](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_view) to have a view for the query and add a read only hibernate entity to map to the view.

Comment: The problem is that the view keeps getting removed after you restart the application. I want to make it permanent if its possible